# Finding if an ideal is the radical of another one...

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

suppose we have, in the ring $\mathbb{Z} [x,y,z,w,v]$, the following polynomials:

$f=xw-yz$,

$g=x^2z-y^3$,

$h=yw^2-z^3$,

$k=xz^2-y^2w$.

The question is to prove that $I=(f,g,h,k)$ is the radical ideal of $J=(f,g,h)$.

I tried several things to no avail: by imposing $x>y>z>w$ I tried to divide $k^2$ by $J$, but since I don't know whether $f,g,h$ is a Grobner base I stopped since having the residual being non zero wouldn't have said anything about it (also, the residual is not zero in this case). I then remembered that if $J$ is primary, the radical is the smallest prime who contains it. But checking that $J$ is primary seems like hell honestly. Since those are not simple polynomials, checking if any power of $k$ is contained in $J$ seems crazy. I could use some kind of software to find a Grobner base of $J$, but I'd like to do it by my own hand, and since my professor didn't explain how to find Grobner bases, I don't think it's the intended method to solve the exercise. Am I comitting some judgement errors here? How do I prove the thesis? Can anybody help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: We have $k^2=z^3g+y^3h-2y^2z^2f\in J$, so $I^2\subseteq J \subseteq I$. So if we can show $I$ is a prime ideal, then we are done. But I don't know if it simplifies the problem or not...

Comment: Macaulay2 confirms that $I$ is prime.

Comment: Ok... So there's no easy way to do it, what a bummer. But thanks a lot for trying to help anyways!

Comment: In what kind of context did this question arise?

Comment: It's an exercise, I re-read it though and the initial ring had one more variable that isn't actually used in defining the polynomials, so the ring would be $\mathbb{Z}[z,y,z,w,v]$ with $v$ not being used in defining the polynomials above.